# Why do I need to create an object for EditText.getText()?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently playing around with Java in Android-Studio.
I stumbled upon a phenomenon I don't understand. When I try to call getText() of a EditText class I first need to create an instance of the EditText class. Could someone please explain why this is?

This works:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.getText();
```

This doesn't:

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).getText();
```

Comment: If `findViewById` creates an object, then it creates an object in both your examples.  The only difference in the first example is that you store the instance in a variable first.  Both examples should be equivalent.  What is the error message you get?

Comment: If you don't like it, try to get familiar with data bindings…

Comment: @Babyburger that's what I thought too. "Can't resolve method 'getText()' is the error I get.

Comment: This is the declaration of `findViewById`: `public T findViewById (int id)` where `T` is `final <T extends View> T`. `EditText` is the grand-child of `View`; therefore, when you do `findViewById(R.id.editText).getText();`, it doesn't know about `getText()` because `View` doesn't have `getText();`. You must cast so it looks as `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText();`. Now, it will know.

Comment: @deHaar thank you, will do that. Looks promising. I would still like to understand why it doesn't work like I expected.

Comment: @acarlstein Thank you! Casting did work. Is this recommended to do? I like to have everything in a line, as I won't do anything else with the editText object.

Comment: @user9413415, its all depends. Just have in consideration that you are expending processing time each time you call `findViewById`. If you are planning to use this `EditText` multiple times (by accessing its methods), then its better to store a reference to such object in a private variable such as `private EditText editText;`. Accessing the object via 'editText' multiple times will be cheaper than calling `findViewById` each time you wish to do something with the `EditText`. Does this make sense? I can explain it in a different way.

Comment: @acarlstein Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the type of the object returned by [View#findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) is generic and will typically be cast automatically to the reference type (in your case, `EditText`) if one is given.

To quote the docs:

> **Note**: In most cases -- depending on compiler support -- the resulting view is automatically cast to the target class type. If the target class type is unconstrained, an explicit cast may be necessary.

If your compiler doesn't know that `findViewById(R.id.editText)` is of type `EditText`, it will not allow you to invoke `getText` (i.e. `android.view.View` does not feature a `getText` method).

Answer (score 2):

In continuation of @mena 's answer , try casting it to edit text. It will work

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because we are writing the EditText in XML file and do the functionality in the java class. 
Due to that reason these two should macth with the id such as below

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Then java class know that there is a EditText with a specific id.

If you directly use as below

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).getText();
```

you will get **NullPointer Exception**.

And also from the **getText()** function it return a object. 
So we cannot set it to a string variable